# PDF with OCR text visible, how to hide it from existing PDF

Tags: pdf, ocr, ghostscript

I have several PDF files that have been OCR-processed (not by me). They contain both the scanned image and the OCR text. They seem to work fine in some viewers (iPhone/iPad), but not in others (Preview.app on macOS) which makes them somewhat awkward to read.

From googling around, it seems that the text & image may be layered incorrectly or there is a problem with the fonts used? I'm not even sure I'm using the correct vocabulary, as most hits I get are worthless.

Is it possible to use ghostscript or something to batch-fix these files?

Example of "bad" rendering:
[image: example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its impossible to say what's wrong with the PDF file (or viewer) without seeing the PDF file, which alse makes it hard to propose solutions!

You could certainly run the file through Ghostscript to the pdfwrite device, and use the -dFILTERTEXT switch to not process the text. The resulting document would therefore not contain the offending text, but would still contain the image.

Of course, this would then not be possible to search or highlight.

You could instead use -dFILTERIMAGE which would remove the original image leaving the text behind. But then anything in the original document which was not text would now be missing.

The usual 'best practice' is to have the text drawn in rendering mode 3, which makes no marks. This allows you to see the original image without the OCR'ed text interfering. Its possible that the viewer you are using is not honouring the text rendering mode, which would be a (fairly serious) bug in the viewer. The most recent versions of MacOS seems to have some nasty bugs in the Quartz PDF rendering engine.

The other way to do this is to draw the text first, then put the original image on top of it, but that's hard to get wrong, I suspect its more likely the text rendering mode.

**EDIT**
The PDF file first draws the text, then draws the image on top of the text. The underlying text should not appear. mkl is quite correct in his comment.

The correct way to fix this is to fix the consumer which is rendering it incorrectly. As I mentioned above the latest version of Quartz seems to have some fairly serious bugs, you might choose to raise this as a bug with Apple.

The only other solution would be to run this through something which will remove the text. Ghostscript can do this but there are implications; firstly it will no longer be possible to search/copy/paste text from the document. Secondly you would need to run quite a complex command line in order to prevent the decompressed JPX images being recompressed as JPEG, which would probably result in compromised quality. Finally the resulting file size would be larger.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; the PDF I took the screenshot from is available [here](http://dis-danmark.dk/bibliotek/905046.pdf). Is there a tool I can use to inspect the PDF to see which rendering mode is used for the text?

Comment: It seems that ABBYY FineReader 12 (which was used to create the files) uses the image/text layering method. Can they be rearranged programmatically?

Comment: I doubt that changing the PDF would really help - any PDF viewer showing the writing in the given PDF is seriously broken, and trying to program around such issues in seriously broken software usually is a loosing battle.